# How will this be different from the previous economics site?

Tags: discussion

There was a previous economics site that ran for a while, but shut down. Was anyone here on that site? Why did it shut down and what can this site do differently?

Answer (score 3):

There were too few people. Also there simply weren't many experts. The quality of questions and answers is much higher now, but there are still very few people.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @CarrKnight. The earlier project failed because not enough experts were attracted during the beta period.  It was largely a lack of experts that killed it. This time we've attracted more experts -- but as CarrKnight notes, there are still few people in total. I'd say we're still doing better than the last time.

Answer (score 0):

I know that S.E. sites are more math oriented, or at least it seems to me, but I think that in order for the site to fare better this time, more applied, methodological-applied questions should be posed and answered. I saw a question about heckman self-selection concept sink down without any interest in the private beta, but we need that kind of questions also.